# Prove $\sqrt{x}>\ln(x)$ in $[1,\infty)$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Well, i try to prove this statement. i choose to make function: $f\left(x\right)\:=\:\sqrt{x}-\ln x$ but the derivative is: $\dfrac{\sqrt{x}\:-\:2}{2\sqrt{x}}$ and it's not always greater than $ 0$. any ideas?

Comment: The derivative is $\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}} - \frac{1}{x}$. It has exactly one zero in $[1,\infty)$. What does that zero signify?

Comment: that from some point x0 f(x)>0 for any x>x0 ?

Comment: Hint: $\ln{e}<\ln{4}<\ln{e^2}=2=\sqrt{4}$.

Comment: @Bryan i don't understand. can you please show me?

Comment: Paired with Cameron's answer, this means that $f$ is positive and increasing on $[4,\infty)$. So we only need to worry about the interval $[1,4]$. A differentiable function on a closed interval attains it minimum at either an endpoint or a critical point. The values that $f$ attains at these points are both greater than $0$.

Answer (score 3):

You miscalculated the derivative. The derivative is actually $f'(x) = \frac{1}{2}x^{-\frac{1}{2}}-x^{-1}$. This is positive for $x > 4$. Then all you need to check is that in the interval $[1,4]$, $\sqrt{x}\ge \ln x$. This can be argued by making use of the first derivative test.

Comment: @DavidMitra No worries. It happens :)

Answer (score 1):

If you set $x=e^z$, you just have to prove that for any $z\geq 0$
$$e^{z/2}\geq z\tag{1}$$
that is true since the exponential function is convex, hence its graphics lies above the graphics of the tangent line in $z=2\log 2$, where the derivative of $e^{z/2}$ equals one:
$$ e^{z/2} \geq (z-2\log 2)+2 > z.\tag{2}$$