Without using MVT, Prove that $\sqrt{x} > \ln(x)$ holds true for all $x > 0$.
I have observed that the inequality $ \sqrt{x} > \ln(x)$ seems to hold for $ x > 0 $.
By plotting the graphs of $ y = \sqrt{x} $ and $ y = \ln{x} $, it appears that $ \ln(x) $ is less than $ \sqrt{x} $ for $ x > 0 $.
However, I would like a rigorous mathematical proof of this inequality. Could someone please help me derive this step by step?

This is not true. For example, $\ln(4) < 2 = \sqrt{4}$. I believe you may have inverted the inequality sign. Also, please format your mathematical statements using MathJax - a guide can be found here

Do you mean the inequality to go the other way?  Also, please use dollar signs $ to indicate latex source.

Thank you for catching that! You’re right  ,I’ve edited the question to reflect the correct inequality ( \sqrt{x} > \ln(x) )

Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/840942/42969

Geometric proof for  $e^x>2x$:
the tangent line of $e^x$ at the point  $(\ln2,2)$ is
$$y=2x+2(1-\ln2).$$
Because $e^x$ is strictly convex on $\mathbb R$, so
$$e^x\geq2x+2(1-\ln2)>2x,\quad \forall x\in\mathbb R.$$
Let $t=e^{2x}$, then
$$\sqrt t>\ln t,\quad \forall t>0.$$

Substituting $x=e^{2t}$, the given inequality is equivalent to
$$
e^t \ge 2t,
$$
for all real $t$. Consider the function $f(t) = e^t -2t$. It’s a sum of two convex functions, so it is convex. In fact, $f(t) \to \infty$ as $|t|\to\infty$, so it has a global minimum. At that minimum, we have $f’(t) = e^t -2 = 0$, which has the unique solution $t_0=\ln2$. Since $f(t_0) = 2-2\ln2 >0$, we conclude that $f(t) >0$ for all $t$.

In what follows, I will assume you are familiar with elementary calculus.
Consider the function $f(x) = \sqrt{x} - \ln(x)$. Differentiating it, we get $f'(x) = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}} - \frac{1}{x}$. Thus, $f'(x) = 0$ if and only if $x = 2\sqrt{x}$. Solving this equation, we have $x = 4$ (since we are considering strictly positive values of $x$). This is a minimum point, as can be seen differentiating again and evaluating at $x = 4$. Thus, we only have to prove that $f(4) > 0$, which can be done by direct computation. As a result, $f(x) > 0$ for all $x > 0$, which is the same as saying $\sqrt{x} > \ln(x)$ for all $x = 0$.

You found that ( x = 4 ) is a minimum for ( f(x) = \sqrt{x} - \ln(x) ), but I’m wondering if this always guarantees a global minimum. For instance, ( g(x) = x^3 + 3x^2 + 2 ) has a local minimum at ( x = 0 ), yet diverges to ( -\infty ).
How does your reasoning ensure ( f(x) > 0 ) for all ( x > 0 )?

@Gauss You are just showing that $f$ has local minimum at $x=4$... This does not prove that the proposed relation holds for any $x>0$. You need to argue that $f''>0$ for all $x>0$, not just at $x=4$. With $f$ being convex, the local minimiser is actually global.

Actually if the minimum is unique in the connected domain (as in this case), then it is also a global minimum.  No analysis of the second derivative is required.

A similar analysis would say $x^k > \log_e(x)$ for all positive $x$ when $k >\frac1e$

@MikhailKatz That's correct, but some additional argument is needed to go from local minimum to global minimum

@AyushSenapati it's because this function (is continuous and) has a local minimum but no local maxima, unlike your example.
